# Using ng add to install ngx-formly in an Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-formly

Node: **12.16.1**

Angular: **9.1.0**

Angular CLI: **9.1.0**

**Problem:** I tried to install **Formly** packages with **ng add** inside an Angular library, but I got:

```
$ ng add @ngx-formly/schematics --ui-theme=material
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Specified module does not exist
```

1) Is it possible to use `ng add` in a library?

2) And if it isn't, is it possible to install Formly in my Angular library in another way? Can I have troubles if I install Formly with:

```
npm install @ngx-formly/core --save
npm install @ngx-formly/material --save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It seems like `ng add` only works when using Angular applications created by Angular CLI. If you try to use `ng add` in an application with a different `sourceRoot` or in a library, it doesn't seem to work.

2) For now, it seems ok to install Formly this way.